# Questions about no duality gap and optimal solutions

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems

My questions are regarding a constrained problem,
$$\min_{x \in X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n} f(x),$$ 
subject to  $g(x) \leq 0 \in \mathbb{R}^m, h(x) =0 \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Its dual problem is $$\sup_{u \geq 0 \in \mathbb{R}^m,v \in \mathbb{R}^k} \theta(u,v),$$ 
where $\theta(u,v):= \inf_{x \in X} \, f(x) + u^T g(x) + v^T h(x)$.

Suppose $x^*$ is primal feasible, and $(u^*,v^*)$ is dual feasible i.e. $u^* \geq 0, v^* \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Define:

Proposition $P$: $f(x^*) = \theta(u^*, v^*)$,

Proposition $Q$: $x^*$ optimizes the primal problem, and $(u^*,v^*)$ optimizes the dual problem.

I was wondering:

1. [Bazaraa's p263 Corollary 2](http://books.google.com/books?id=Mw5HFRkCdQgC&pg=PA263&dq=solve%20the%20primal%20and%20dual%20problems,%20respectively.&hl=en&ei=QOiYTbDOH4e90QHF1NjxCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=solve%20the%20primal%20and%20dual%20problems,%20respectively.&f=false)
   says: $P \longrightarrow
       Q$. Is $Q \longrightarrow
       P$ also true, or when?
2. When $P$ is true, will $x^*$ solve
   the inner subproblem of the dual
   problem when $(u,v)$ is fixed at
   $(u^*, v^*)$, i.e., $$ f(x^*) +
       u^{*T} g(x^*) + v^{*T} h(x^*) =
       \inf_{x \in X} \, f(x) + u^{*T} g(x)
       + v^{*T} h(x)?$$
3. When $Q$ is true, will $x^*$
   solve the inner subproblem of the
   dual problem when $(u,v)$ is fixed
   at $(u^*, v^*)$? If not always, possible to tell when this will happen?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Did you forget to state convexity assumptions? Is $f$ convex? Is $g$ concave? Is $h$ linear?

Comment: @Dominique: I think I was talking about the general case, and there is no such assumption on f, g and h. See the Bazaraa's book link.